# Send request from one android app to another app using a Web server

Tags: android, webserver

I am doing my Semester project of Android.I am making a food delivery app.The work I have to do is that the user will send the request to a nearest restaurant.
The restaurant will accept the request and deliver the desired order that a user requested.

I know I have to work with maps and webserver.Maps will be used to get the location of the user and I am pretty good working on that.I know how to connect the android app with webserver as well.

But, I don't know how the user from his app will send request to the restaurant app by using webserver.How the resturant will accept and which restaurant will accept (in my case a nearest restaurant should accept,but first I just need to connect the user with restuarant).
Need a guide or Tutorials how I should Start this.I am really confused.

Comment: Hi Nabeel, generally webservers are not used for real-time updates which an app like this would require. Perhaps it would be better to look into a more realtime technology

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you use Firebase - [https://firebase.google.com/?hl=pt-br][1] - to receive/send messages throught web. It´s very simple to use!